# How do I use the output of a function as input for a matplotlib graph

Tags: python

I am new to coding and doing I'm doing my first python project. I'm making a function that takes in the spread of a sports game, the over/under, and the team names to graph the expected results of the game. I can't figure out how to get the favteam and underdog function parameter inputs as formatted names later on when I am graphing the results in maplotlib. Here is what I have so far:

```
def getfinalscore(spread, total, favteam, underdog):
    x = ((total + spread)/2)
    y = total - x
    total = x + y
    spread = x - y
    print(f"The projected outcome of the game is:\n")
    print(f"{favteam.title():<15}{x:>1}")
    print(f"{underdog.title():<15}{y:>1}")

    print("\nFavteam Projected Points:")
    favteam_points = f"0, {x/4},  {x/4+ x/4},  {x/4 + x/4 + x/4},  {x/4 + x/4 + x/4 + x/4}"
    print(favteam_points)
    print("\nUnderdog projected points:")
    underdog_points = f"0, {y/4},  {y/4+ y/4},  {y/4 + y/4 + y/4},  {y/4 + y/4 + y/4 + y/4}"
    print(underdog_points)

getfinalscore(1,218,suns,clippers) 
#(or whatever game you would like to see graphed)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,10))
Quarter = ['0','12','24','36','48']
Points1 = favteam_points
Points2 = underdog_points
plt.plot(Quarter, Points1, label = favteam, color = '', lw = 1, marker = '*', ms = 10)
plt.plot(Quarter, Points2, label = underdog, color = '', lw = 1, marker = '*', ms = 10)
plt.title('Game Spread Projection')
plt.xlabel('Quarter (in minutes)')
plt.ylabel('Expected Points')
plt.legend(fontsize = 'large', loc=9)
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
print("Favorite team slope")
favteamslope = print(Points1.pop()/48)
print("\nUnderdog slope")
underdogslope = print(Points2.pop()/48)
```

The favteam_points, underdog_points, favteam, and underdog all come back as not defined in the matplotlob section even though I clearly defined them in my function.
I also want to figure out a way to get the color of the team automatically from the input of the team, for example if the team is the Suns I want the line color to be orange, if its the Nets I want the line color to be black, etc. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You have different Namespaces. You need to return the values out of the function.

```
def function(x):
   y = x^2
   return y

y = function(10)
```

The favteam_points variable is only defined in the function outside of it its not.

```
def getfinalscore(spread, total, favteam, underdog):
    ...
    return (faveteam_points, underdog_points)

faveteam_points, underdog_points = getfinalscore(1,218,suns,clippers)
```